# Where was gem downloaded from?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I have a gem that has an old dependency that is causing errors. I checked the gem's repo on Github and I can see that the dependency was removed and is no longer in there. That begs the question, where was the my local gem downloaded from?

How do I figure out where my gem was downloaded from? Can I figure out which branch it came from? I have Bundler if that makes a difference.

Comment: I'm not sure "That begs the question" follows from your discoveries so far. Code changes over time. Your gem was *probably* downloaded from Rubygems as normal, unless you have further evidence that was not the case. Could you show *your* Gemfile - the top line showing source location, and the line for the problem gem?

Comment: Check Gemfile whether it specifies the old gem separately or with a git url?